# Notepad++ Line Break after every sentence?

Tags: notepad++, break, sentence

How do a create a line break after every period? I simply want every sentence to be on a new line in notepad++. I have read through the threads and didn't find anything addressing this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try replacing "." with ".\n", does that work?

Comment: Try Quick Text plugin, it allows to set up autocomplete [link] (http://lifehacker.com/5686272/how-to-get-more-plus-out-of-notepad%252B%252B)

Answer (score 0):

Select *Extended* Search Mode in bottom left of Replace window and replace "." with ".\n" .

Comment: As I understand author wants "real time" substitution, probably some autocomplete plugin should be used for this purpose like Quick Text

Comment: Notepad++ has macro feature which can be used to store and playback the function.

Comment: Yes this worked thanks! "Select Extended Search Mode in bottom left of Replace window and replace "." with ".\n" ."